# Generate random number and keep it in a cookie using c#

Tags: c#, cookies, random

i am trying to generate random number and keep it in a cookie using c#, here is my cookie named as cart

```
Response.Cookies["cart"].Value = RandomNumber(10, 50);
Response.Cookies["cart"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
```

now i got a generator here in this code

```
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
  Random random = new Random();
  return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

i tried to equal the cookie with RandomNumber but an error said :Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'   .

any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 4):

Cookie values are strings, so use `ToString()` to convert the `int` to a `string`:

```
Response.Cookies["cart"].Value = RandomNumber(10, 50).ToString();
```

Comment: is there any oppurtinity that the random number generate say (23) twice, and how can i deny that ?

Comment: @Bader: Sure, it could.  It is virtually certain that you will get the same value twice by the time you call it enough times (in this case, 41-42 times).  If you require uniqueness, consider using [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) instead.  It will probably make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: you can keep track of the numbers that have already been generated in a list or an array.  Then everytime you generate a new number check the list and if its in there already, regenerate a new random number.

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign the return value of RandomNumber(10,50) to Response.Cookies["cart"].Value because Value is expecting a string not an int.  try using toString on the return value and then assigning it to Response.Cookies["cart"].Value